# Java:Convention / practice for calling parent class methods

Tags: java, subclass, parent, super

For following code :

`

```
Class A
{
method1();
method2();
}

Class B extends A
{
method1();
method3();
}`
```

In Class B, method3 implementation is as follows:

```
method3()
{ 
this.method1(); // For calling method1 in class B
super.method1(); // For calling method1 in parent class A

// Following statements call method 2 in parent class
method2();      // 1 doesn't seem to be right practice
this.method2;   // 2 is more readable in case method2 is overridden in this class
super.method2();// 3 improves readability IMO
}
```

Which of the 3 is recommended way to call method2?

Comment: Calling super.method() is quite rare, especially if not called from an override of that method. Nobody would expect it, so best to just avoid it. So adding `this.` to a method call is just superfluous information.

Comment: You would only use super.method() if you have overridden method2() inside of class B.

Comment: I understand that both 1 & 2 will result in "this.method2()" when the code is compiled, and was interested in knowing which one is preferred way of calling it. Incase of method1(), I saw some posts which said - "this.method1()" should be preferred way of calling it than "method1()" as a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR:

Using `this.` to call methods is useless. Using `super.` to call methods is required to avoid infinite recursion.

For calling methods, both `this.foo()` and `foo()` do the same thing: call the most derived version of a given method. (For accessing member variables, things are different). There is no way in Java AFAIK to call "this class' version of a method".

`super` is usually used in the context of overriding methods, to invoke base class' implementation of the method. If you omit `super.` you end up with method calling itself and potentially with infinite recursion. If you use `super.method()` in any other context, you've probably messed up your class hierarchy.